# Mathematical expression from string to int

Tags: javascript

Are there any easy way in javascript to transform a mathematical expression from a string to a int. For example, from this:
`var a = "5 + 5 - 7";`
to this `var b = 5 + 5 - 7;`

Thank you!

Comment: Like `eval(a)` ?

Comment: `eval` does this, but with javascript expressions not math ones. For mathematical expressions, you have to write your own parser and interpreter.

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know about `eval(a)` but it works perfectly. :)